# Does es2015 and react need to be explicitly configured in Babel?

Tags: javascript, plugins, webpack, babeljs, preset

I was reading from this [article](https://www.fullstackreact.com/articles/what-are-babel-plugins-and-presets/) about `webpack` `presets` vs `plugins` and the author said:

[image]

So if `es2015` and `react` are automatically enabled, why does he still put them in the `babelrc` or configure them in the `package.json`? Are those `presets` purely just for example-sake and never need to be done in practice?

Comment: That's wrong. It's NOT `automatically`, man. You need to install these packages to `enable` it: `babel-preset-es2015` (for `es2015`), and `babel-preset-stage-0` (for `stage-3`)

Comment: So after you install them do you still need to put them in your babelrc?

Comment: No, just install and config them in the file `webpack.config.js` (in the root of your project). But `package.json` is required.